# How to know whether bot is idle or busy in BluePrism

Tags: blueprism

Any idea how to know whether bot is idle or busy running some process in BP?

We can do it by getting status of bots from database but want to know how to get the status.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What are you trying to accomplish by having this data available at the process level?

Comment: @esqew Basically I want to know which all bots are idle and which all are running when ever required. Its for monitoring purpose. Instead of going manually and check, can we check this in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the "Available Resources" pane in the Control tab is for; it lists each registered resource in the current environment as well as the current status for each.

---

If you absolutely must have the information available at the Blue Prism process level, you could use a list of IP/Port combinations of known runtime resources to make a GET call to each one using their `status` endpoint.

A call to `http://localhost:8181/status` on the runtime resource itself yields the following response body when idle:

```
RESOURCE UNIT
Total running: 0
```

Using some creative substringing or regular expressions, you could extract the status from this string for each of your runtime resources.